# Exporting an sql task to a grid

Tags: ssis

I would like a simple example of running a SQL statement "SQLTest.sql". It is  located in the C:\MYSQL folder on the C drive. I would like to send the output to a grid.

Comment: What's _"a grid"_?

Comment: screen output that looks like a spreadsheet.

Comment: Doesn't sound like something you want to do in SSIS...

Comment: the simple example is using ssis.